# Como passar variáveis "invisíveis" de uma página para outra usando um link no Django?

Tags: python, django, url

Imagine que eu tenha o seguinte código no urls.py;
`url(r'^relatorio', views.relatorioView, name='relatorio'), url(r'^relatorio/grafico', views.graph, name='grafico'),`

Na página relatório eu tenho uma tabela com nomes e códigos de itens.
Como eu posso fazer um link que redirecione para a página do gráfico daquele determinado item sem deixar o código explícito na url?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um POST, e enviar os dados para a outra view. Ela faz a query set e retorna uma resposta, mas como você enviou por POST, os identificadores não vão aparecer na url. Mas você tem que estar preparado para um solicitação get, na mesma view, nessa caso, você pode redirecionar o usuário para outra parte do site.

Isso você pode fazer com funcition views assim(isso está [nessa](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response) documentação):

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
        do_something()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
       do_something_else()
```

Com classes, você usaria os métodos apropriados para cada tipo de requisição.

Para pegar o valor passado pro POST, você pode fazer:

```
request.POST['chave-do-valor']
```

Use um form, para enviar os dados, você deve especificar o enctype. Para o código acima funcionar.

```
<form action="/view-url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```